# How did Batman survive when he was stabbed?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-dark-knight-rises

Near the end of **The Dark Knight Rises**, Batman was stabbed by Miranda. After a while Batman took his bat and flew away to detonate the bomb. Then at the end of the movie he was at the dining table with Selina Kyle.

How is it possible for Batman to survive when he was strongly stabbed by Miranda?

Comment: He is alive because he fixed the auto pilot right before. They even noted the patch by bruce wayne. I dont even think he went out in it.

Comment: @multiplexnova converted yoru answer to a comment because the question is about him surviving being stabbed, not surviving the bomb blast.

Comment: I don't understand how she could have stabbed him at all when, in Batman Begins, Lucius Fox says that the batsuit could stop a knife. Was there an announced revision to the suit in TDK that would have allowed this to happen? I don't remember.

Comment: @riddler that sounds like an excellent question to post!

Comment: @Riddler thats in Batman begins In Dark knight batman wants to be more agile so they reduce the heavy armor padding and replace it with a lighter version,  to which fox remarks stating that even though he is agile he is more susceptible to gun fire and knives. (he changes the armor after he gets mauled by the dog in Batman's introduction scene)

Comment: So , is official that batman has survived ,its not just alferd day dreaming. For me , movie has open ending either he survived or alferd's imagination

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a difference getting stabbed normally and with the bat suit on which could absorb some of the major damage intended. We can assume the fact that he is using the same suit he used from Dark Knight at this point, although one more curious point to note is during the earlier scene when he meets Lucius Fox for the first time in the third movie he seems to be making stuff keeping Batman in mind and there is quite a possibility that he could've upgraded the suit from the Dark knight to be more robust and i think its a strong possibility

When Miranda stabs him she doesn't intend it to be the killing blow because after stabbing him, she remarks to Bane to keep him alive till Gotham blows to dust. I think she missed a vital spot on purpose (given the fact she was trained by the League of Shadows) and he survives a straight shot in Dark Knight from Two face. I think this knife would be relatively easier to withstand in my perspective.

Answer (score 5):

Bullet resistant material is not the same as knife resistance for those geniuses out there.

The first lines [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulletproof_vest) contain a description of such equipments and they sound pretty similar to those worn by Batman:

> [on ballistic vest]: "Metal or ceramic plates can be used with a soft vest, providing additional protection from rifle rounds, and metallic components or tightly woven fiber layers can give soft armor resistance to stab and slash attacks from knives and similar close-quarter weapons."

It seems to me that Batman was using a soft vest with metal or ceramic plates, without the other fiber for mobility reasons.

Getting stabbed hurts, that is why he was in pain. Common sense thrown in for fun, one can see she was an experience assassin, so she would have known where to hit for it not to be deadly.

Comment: OP is not asking where batman was stabbed or not. He is already convinced that the batawan was stabbed , question is how he survived

Answer (score 4):

The other answers haven't mentioned the exact scene in which Fox tells Batman about the Kevlar. It's pretty much self-explanatory. In Batman Begins, this is this exchange;

> **Fox**: Nomex survival suit for advanced infantry. Kevlar bi-weave, reinforced joints.
>
> **Bruce**: Tear-resistant?
>
> **Fox**: This sucker will stop a knife.
>
> **Bruce**: Bulletproof?
>
> **Fox**: Anything but a straight shot.

It's almost like Nolan was indicating something about Batman getting stabbed later in the movies.

Comment: Read the comments on the question. You're speaking about *Batman Begins*, but he had his suited lightened in *The Dark Knight* which made him more vulnerable to guns and knives. Also it doesn't look like the knive didn't get through the suit. He really looked hurt from the knive (but I agree that it might not have been that serious a wound).

Comment: @ChristianRau Nope. Wrong. _More_ vulnerable doesn't mean **VULNERABLE**. It's still armour but more _vulnerable_ than _before_. The knife wound couldn't have penetrated vital parts. Kevlar's thickness alone will stop the knife.